# .net core 3.0, Service not register using HostBuilder for Integration Tests

Tags: c#, testing, .net-core, integration-testing

The repository is available here: https://github.com/ranouf/TestingWithDotNetCore3_0/tree/WithDatabase

I'm looking for a way to upgrade from .Net Core 2.0 to 3.0 my Integration Tests.
I really try my best to be able to inject a damned service, as you can see, I tried every where I could:

```
        var hostBuilder = new HostBuilder()
            .UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory())
            .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
            {
                logging.ClearProviders();
                logging.AddXunit(Output);
            })
            .ConfigureServices(services =>
            {
                services.AddAutofac();
                services.AddSingleton<IMyService, MyService>(); //Here
            })
            .ConfigureContainer<ContainerBuilder>(builder =>
            {
                builder.RegisterType<MyService>().As<IMyService>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();//Here
            })
            .ConfigureWebHost(webHost =>
            {
                // Add TestServer
                webHost
                    .UseStartup<TestStartup>()
                    .UseTestServer()
                    .ConfigureServices(services =>
                    {
                        services.AddSingleton<IMyService, MyService>();//Here
                        services.AddAutofac();
                        services
                            .AddControllers()
                            .AddApplicationPart(typeof(TestStartup).Assembly);
                    })
                    .ConfigureTestServices(services =>
                    {
                        services.AddSingleton<IMyService, MyService>();//Here
                        services.AddAutofac();
                        services
                            .AddControllers()
                            .AddApplicationPart(typeof(TestStartup).Assembly);
                    })
                    .ConfigureTestContainer<ContainerBuilder>(builder =>
                    {
                        builder.RegisterType<MyService>().As<IMyService>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();//Here
                    });
            });
```

But guess what? It doesnt work at all ... I really don't know how I can make the HostBuilder understand ... 
Of course I tried to alternativaly keep only one way to inject my service

So when I want to get the Service:

```
    Host = hostBuilder.Start();
        Server = Host.GetTestServer();
        Client = Host.GetTestClient();

        using (var scope = Host.Services.CreateScope())
        {
            var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
            try
            {
                var myService = services.GetRequiredService<MyService>();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Output.WriteLine("HOST: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
        using (var scope = Server.Services.CreateScope())
        {
            var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
            try
            {
                var myService = services.GetRequiredService<MyService>();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Output.WriteLine("SERVER: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

The error message is:

> The requested service 'MyAPI.Services.MyService' has not been
>   registered. To avoid this exception, either register a component to
>   provide the service, check for service registration using
>   IsRegistered(), or use the ResolveOptional() method to resolve an
>   optional dependency.

How do you succeed to inject a service in HostBuilder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have registered that whenever someone asks for `IMyService` give them an instance of `MyService` - but you are asking for `MyService` directly and DI doesn't know anything about it.

You need to change your registration to:

```
builder.RegisterType<MyService>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

Or ask for the interface not the class:

```
services.GetRequiredService<IMyService>();
```

Also, you only need to register it in the `ConfigureContainer` method.

Comment: Yeah I just saw that! You are true !! Thanks